# Extract URLS,BOOKMARKS, MARKUPs and Comments from a pdf using PyPDF2 or Pdfminer

Tags: python, python-3.x, pdfminer, pypdf

I tried to extract pdf urls,comments or bookmarsk from the pdf using pypdf2 or pdfminer. I cant see /Annots or URI even if there are urls or bookmarsk present in the pdf.

Comment: How are you expecting someone to answer this question? You've provided no example file, no code details, no elaboration of the precise issue you are facing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using PyMuPDF I was able to extract links and bookmarks from the pdf.
How to install PyMuPDF
1. pip install PyMuPDF
there are direct methods to extract bookmarks and hyperlinks from the pdf.
See the documentation from below links.
http://pymupdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial/#inspecting-the-links-of-a-page
http://pymupdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial/#working-with-outlines

If anybody knows how to extract comments and marksups from the pdf please let me know?